# What is the meaning of the last argument passed to the ColorFunction of a ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, undocumented

According to the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html), the meaning of the arguments passed to `ParametricPlot3D` is $x, y, z, u, v$.  This is 5 arguments: the Cartesian coordinates and the two parameters.  Similarly, for `ParametricPlot` it's $x, y, u, v$.

Let's look at how many arguments are *actually* passed to the `ColorFunction`:

```
Reap[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]}, 
       {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, ColorFunction -> ((Sow[{##}]; Gray) &)]]
```

If you evaluate this, you'll notice that actually 6 arguments are passed to the colour function, but the last one is always zero.  If we use the one-parameter form of `ParametricPlot3D`, then still six arguments will be passed, but now the last *two* are zero.

```
Reap[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], 0}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> ((Sow[{##}]; Gray) &)]]
```

Similarly, the colour function of `ParametricPlot` receives 5 arguments instead of 4.

**What is the meaning of the last argument passed to the `ColorFunction` of these functions?  Does it have any use?  Does `ParametricPlot3D` have a form where the last argument of the colour function will not be zero and has an application?**

Comment: I just tested with `RegionPlot3D` and plain `Plot`: Both also add an extra `0.` argument.

Comment: "Reserved for future use"?

Comment: @Sjoerd Well, they could always just add one more argument ...

Comment: Interesting -- this explians why a color function defined per the ColorFunction docs with 5 arguments doesn't work!! mycolor[x_, y_, z_, u_, v_] := Red; ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, ColorFunction -> (mycolor[##] &)] produces an 'uncolored' figure.. Apologies I cant see how to post a comment vs an 'answer' here..

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit speculative but I note that `SphericalPlot3D[]` supplies *its* `ColorFunction` with 6 args, being x, y, z, theta, phi, *and r*.  `SphericalPlot3D` can be shown to call `ParametricPlot3D`, so I'd surmise the extra argument is left there for compatibility.

Comment: Sounds plausible +1

Comment: How did you find this out? Did you use `Trace`?

Comment: `Unprotect[ParametricPlot3D];ParametricPlot3D[arg___] := (Print["arg list is", {arg}]); SphericalPlot3D[1, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {p, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, ColorFunction -> colorfunction ]`